# I need to find the count of even and odd primenumbers from a file. What is wrong with my code?

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    FILE *ptr;
    int n;
    int count1 = 0; //count for even
    int count2 = 0; //count for odd
    int count3 = 0; //count for prime
    int flag = 0;

    ptr = fopen("trial.txt", "r");
    n = getw(ptr);

    while(n != EOF)
    {
        if(n%2 == 0)
            count1++;
        else
            count2++;
        
        if(n > 1)
        {
            for(int i = 2; i < n/2; i++)
            {
                if(n%i == 0)
                flag = 1;                
            }
            if(flag == 0)
                count3++;                       
        }

        flag = 0;
        n = getw(ptr);
    }

    fclose(ptr);

    printf("this file has %d even %d odd and %d prime numbers", count1, count2, count3);

    return 0;
}
```

Above program should return the count of even, odd, and prime numbers.

I have created a text file which contains the numbers I want to count. If it contains `2, 4, 6, 8`, e.g.,
my program should return with the following output:
`2 even 0 odd 0 prime`.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/iXrB2.jpg    - this is the text file

Comment: Have you checked if your program works with hard coded values instead of reading from a file?

Comment: If yes, have you checked that you can print the numbers in the text file one by one?

Comment: OT: use meaningful variable names like `evencount`, `oddcount`, `primecount`. Then you can remove the comments as well.

Comment: Also, use consistent indentation when you post.

Comment: Can you add the file you are trying to read? I think you have a misconception about getw

Comment: You must check the file open attempt, especially when the file spec uses the 'current directory' - something designed for interactive, human users, not apps:(

Comment: @DownloadPizza added a ss of the text file

Comment: The problem is that `getw` reads char by char as an int, so if you have a file "ABC" its going to read 65,66,67. So the example "2,4,6,8" evaluates to 50,44,52,44,54,44,56

Comment: @saahilsabu please read the top answer

Comment: For `2, 4, 6, 8`, I would have expected `4 even 0 odd 1 prime`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out in comments, I think there is a problem in how you're reading integer values from file.

The `int getw(FILE *)` function is for reading an integer directly from the bytes of a file, not for reading an integer from the textual contents of a file.

I added a `printf("n = %d\n", n);` in your while loop to see what integer values were getting processed. When I ran it, I found this:

```
c-posts : $ gcc readoddevenfromfile.c 
c-posts : $ ./a.out 
n = 171051569
n = 171182643
n = 171313717
n = 171444791
n = 808520249
this file has 0 even 5 odd and 1 prime numbers
```

I think you should us `fgets()` to read file line by line and then use `sscanf()` to extract integer from line like this:

```c
    char line[10]; 
    
    ptr = fopen("trial.txt","r");
    while(fgets(line, 10, ptr))
    {
        sscanf(line, "%d", &n);
        // Check whether n is even, odd or prime
```

Or If you have integers in a single line(as provided in your screenshot). You can read them one by one using `fscanf` like this:

```c
    ptr = fopen("trial.txt","r");
    while(fscanf(ptr, "%d", &n) != EOF)
    {
      // Check whether n is odd, even or prime
```

Answer (score 1):

Rohan Kumar is right, you should use `fgets()` or `fscanf()`, instead of `getw()`, because you're reading a text file. Let me share an example of working code I wrote using `fscanf()`. I also changed the condition of the for loop, writing i <= n/2 instead of i < n/2.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    char info[100];
    FILE * ptr = fopen("trial.txt","r");
    int n, i, flag;

    int count1 =0; //count for even
    int count2= 0; //count for odd
    int count3=0; //count for prime

    do
    {
        flag = 0;

        if (fscanf(ptr, "%d", &n) == 0) break;
        else
        {
            if (n%2 == 0) count1 += 1; /* check if the number is even  */
            else count2 += 1;

            for (i = 2; i <= n/2; ++ i) /* check if the number is prime */
            {
                if (n%i == 0) flag = 1;
            } 
            if (flag == 0) count3 += 1;
        }
    } while (!feof(ptr));

    fclose(ptr);

    printf("\nThis file has %d even, %d odd and %d prime numbers.\n",count1,count2,count3);

    return 0;
}
```

Hope this could help you,

Giovanni Pachera

Answer (score 0):

I tried in my vim editor
use fgets() instead of getw
the program gives the expected answer